# Trying to access cart items using foreach in a plugin but getting critical error on edit and setting pages in admin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, dokan

I'm using Dokan-woocommerce-wordpress.
trying to access the vendor ID of items added in cart, using foreach inside a plugin file.

```
// Get Vendor UPI ID and Murchant Code
        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
         
        foreach( $items as $my_cart_item ){
            $my_product_id = $my_cart_item['product_id'];
        }
        
        
        $vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $my_product_id );
        $store_details = get_user_meta($vendor_id, 'dokan_profile_settings');
        $upi_id = $store_details[0]['vendor_upi_id'];
        $murchant_code = $store_details[0]['vendor_upi_murchant_code'];
```

The above code is giving the desired output but something from here is causing critical error and "edit" pages not opening in wordpress admin.

[image]

This is the error log msg

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/cardocte/public_html/shreeroyals.com/wp-content/plugins/upi-qr-code-payment-for-woocommerce/includes/payment.php on line 57
```

Please suggest any solution for it.

Comment: There has been a critical error on this website. **Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.** What is in that email or in the error log files? 
In any case what causes the problem and therefore the shortest way to the solution. 
In short, important information that is missing in your question.

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r for indicating, I've updated the question with error log msg

Comment: Where do you execute this stuff?

Comment: I'm executing above code inside a plugin file. Its a QR code based payment plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It seems that `get_cart()` causes problems if it is executed in the admin area so wrapping the above snippet in conditional: `if( ! is_admin() ) { }` fixed the issue for me.